# How do I make an Android device "ring" using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, webrtc

I am new to React Native, coming from React. I am building a video messaging app that uses WebRTC, React Native (native / no Expo) and I have wrongly assumed that making the device "ring" would be as simple as calling an inbuilt method, like you would with `Alert` for example.

When a logged in user of the app receives notification of an incoming call, I would like the phone to ring, much in the same way as you would see in WhatsApp or Skype when you have an incoming call.

I have searched the web and haven't really found anything very useful - it may be that I am using the wrong search terms because I don't know what I'm looking for.

Any pointers gratefully accepted and understand that getting this to work require a number of steps to be taken!

Comment: My means this module was able to change the volume of the device. I'm afraid I've got the wrong idea of your question.

Comment: Thank you for removing your reply.

Comment: did you find any proper solution? can you please share here.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to access native APIs to do the equivalent of ringing the phone for VoIP calls.  The recommended iOS APIs are [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit). The recommended Android APIs are [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService).

The [React Native CallKeep Library](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) should have the utility you need or serve as a reference if you're building a custom implementation.